# UITableView self sizing cell scrolling issues with big difference of cell height

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios8, uitableviewautomaticdimension

```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

    let json = JSON(data: activityTableView.onlineFeedsData)[indexPath.row] // new
    if(json["topic"]["reply_count"].int > 0){
        if let cell: FeedQuestionAnswerTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(kCellIdentifier_reply) as? FeedQuestionAnswerTableViewCell{

            cell.selectionStyle = .None
            cell.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.relatedTableView = self.activityTableView
            cell.configureFeedWithReplyCell(cell, indexPath: indexPath, rect: view.frame,key: "activityTableView")
            // Make sure the constraints have been added to this cell, since it may have just been created from scratch
            cell.layer.shouldRasterize = true
            cell.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale

            return cell
        }
    }else{
        if let cell: FeedQuestionTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(kCellIdentifier) as? FeedQuestionTableViewCell{

            cell.selectionStyle = .None
            cell.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.relatedTableView = self.activityTableView
            cell.configureFeedCell(cell, indexPath: indexPath, rect: view.frame)
            // Make sure the constraints have been added to this cell, since it may have just been created from scratch

            cell.layer.shouldRasterize = true
            cell.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
            return cell
        }
    }


    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

There is difference of 200-400 in height in each cell,So tried implementing the height calculation in `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath` .I cant the exact estimate height in this method as bcz of calculation

and caching the height in `willDisplayCell` method but still the scroll jumps like is it taking time to rendering .

The cell is like the Facebook card type layout with lots of dynamic data  with variable height text and images.Can someone help me in this .Thanks

Comment: Can you tell me more about how to calculate the height of the cell in `tableView(_:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:)`?

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to calculate each cells height, just use the tableView(_:heightForRowAtIndexPath) instead of estimatedRowHeightAtIndexPath property. estimatedRowHeightAtIndexPath is mostly used in smthg like selfsizing cells etc.

Comment: NSMutableDictionary *cellHeightsDictionary; // initialize in code
    cellHeightsDictionary = @{}.mutableCopy;

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. I hope this could help you. It's worked for me. Actually this calculates the cell height before it displayed.
Thanks.

```
NSMutableDictionary *cellHeightsDictionary;
```

// Put this in viewDidLoad

```
cellHeightsDictionary = @{}.mutableCopy;
```

// UITableview delegate Methods

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0)
{
    NSNumber *height = [cellHeightsDictionary objectForKey:indexPath];
    if (height) return height.doubleValue;
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [cellHeightsDictionary setObject:@(cell.frame.size.height) forKey:indexPath];

}
```

Comment: thnks @yogesh i will definetly try , but i ended up removing autolayout and code it in frame based using AsyncdisplayKit to acheive ma requirements